# Error in SQL Developer during creating tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create 3 tables using SQL Developer and have an error. Can't undersand why it happens.

```
Create table Album
(
  "alb_code" integer primary key,
  "alb_name" char(50),
  "publ" char(50),
  "publ_date" date not null
);
Create table Song
(
  "song_code" integer primary key,
  "song_name" char(50),
  "auth" char(50),
  "year" integer,
  "style" char(30)
);
Create table Song_from_Album
(
  "in_alb_code" integer primary key,
  "time" float,
  "no" integer,
  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Song("song_code"),
  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Album("alb_code")
);
```

I get an error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
Create table Album
(
  "alb_code" integer primary key,
  "alb_name" char(50),
  "publ" char(50),
  "publ_date" date not null
)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: имя уже задействовано для существующего объекта
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 8 in command -
Create table Song
(
  "song_code" integer primary key,
  "song_name" char(50),
  "auth" char(50),
  "year" integer,
  "style" char(30)
)
Error at Command Line : 8 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: имя уже задействовано для существующего объекта
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 16 in command -
Create table Song_from_Album
(
  "in_alb_code" integer primary key,
  "time" float,
  "no" integer,
  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Song("song_code"),
  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Album("alb_code")
)
Error at Command Line : 21 Column : 15
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00906: отсутствует левая скобка
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Seems they are already created. If the intent is to re-create, drop them first: `drop table song_from_album; drop table Song; drop table Album;`

Comment: also, remove all of the quotes from your columns names - making them case sensitive will ONLY create problems for you going forward.

Answer (score 0):

The first two tables are getting created, but third table has error.

Drop the tables and recreate with correction to third table syntax

The error "missing left parenthesis" is with the foreign key constraint declaration,

Use this instead

```
  CONSTRAINT fk_no FOREIGN KEY ("no") REFERENCES Song("song_code"),
  CONSTRAINT fk_alb_code FOREIGN KEY ("in_alb_code") REFERENCES Album("alb_code")
```

With this change, `Song_Album` table declaration will be like this

```
Create table Song_from_Album
(
  "in_alb_code" integer primary key,
  "time" float,
  "no" integer,
  CONSTRAINT fk_no FOREIGN KEY ("no") REFERENCES Song("song_code"),
  CONSTRAINT fk_alb_code FOREIGN KEY ("in_alb_code") REFERENCES Album("alb_code")
);
```